# subject not found confluent kafka schema registry error_code":40401,"message

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

I am using Kafka confluent schema registry docker image, when I test it locally (with a kafka installed locally, this works as expected, but when I try to use it with a remote Kafka cluster, I got an error :

`{"error_code":40401,"message":"Subject not found. io.confluent.rest.exceptions.RestNotFoundException: Subject not found.\nio.confluent.rest.exceptions.RestNotFoundException: Subject not found.\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.exceptions.Errors.subjectNotFoundException(Errors.java:51)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SubjectVersionsResource.listVersions(SubjectVersionsResource.java:157)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Delegat`ingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat `java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat`

below is the command I use it to run the docker

```
docker run  --network host -p 8081:8081        -e  SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=first_broker:9092,second_broker:9092,third_broker:9092    -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=0.0.0.0     -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8081     -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEBUG=true confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:latest
```

The error stack I got is :

```
    Producer clientId=producer-1] Updated cluster metadata updateVersion 2 to MetadataCache{cluster=Cluster(id = dIU-fffyfHXRDeVgZA4fud_eBw, nodes = [first_broker:9092 (id: 2 rack: subnret-0ecf514e9ghg94d5197a7), second_broker:9092 (id: 1 rack: subrnet-0befbedzd392e5497137), third_broker:9092 (id: 3 rack: subnret-0rrc00cc1dbd14c0350)], partitions = [Partition(topic = topics, partition = 0, leader = 1, replicas = [1,3,2], isr = [1,3,2], offlineReplicas = [])], controller = first_broker:9092 (id: 3 rack: subnret-0c0rr0cc1dbd14c0350))}
Sending POST with input {"schema":"\"string\""} to http://0.0.0.0:8081/subjects/topicName-value/versions
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:851)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:8
```

I noticed that in the remote Kafka cluster I got the _schemas topic created  But when I use the consumer console to read the data from this topic `_shemas` , I got the following results :

```
{"keytype":"NOOP","magic":0}-null
{"keytype":"NOOP","magic":0}-null
{"keytype":"NOOP","magic":0}-null
{"keytype":"NOOP","magic":0}-null
{"keytype":"NOOP","magic":0}-null
{"keytype":"NOOP","magic":0}-null
{"keytype":"NOOP","magic":0}-null
{"keytype":"NOOP","magic":0}-null
{"keytype":"NOOP","magic":0}-null
{"keytype":"NOOP","magic":0}-null
{"keytype":"NOOP","magic":0}-null
{"keytype":"NOOP","magic":0}-null
{"keytype":"NOOP","magic":0}-null
```

Any idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

`SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME` should be a resolvable host name, and not `0.0.0.0`

Similarly, don't use `http://0.0.0.0:8081` in your producer code.

The listeners are the bind address, but they can be left out as well, as long as you have the port forwarded, and you remove `--network host`

You can ignore the `NOOP` messages from the Registry (it spits two of those out at startup to find the very end of the topic)